# How to specially customize a theme using WordPress.com?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, customization

I’m working on a site for a client of mine who wants it to look exactly like Tamera Mowry site http://tameramowry.com.

This is what her site looks like now http://www.lemonsandflats.com/. She is using WordPress.com. I told her that while using WordPress.com, it would be very difficult to make her site look exactly like Tamera’s with the exact blog layout and everything.

I explained to her the difference between Wordpress.com and WordPress.org.

If she was using WordPress.org it would have been a different story.

Without having access to her php files, would you think it would be possible to give her exactly what she wants?

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can get exactly what you want without touching the PHP files,
Just find a template that look similar to the structure of your desired site, 
Find a good visual composer, you can customize everything from the front.